# Monitor 3G and Wifi data usage

Tags: 8.0, nokia-lumia-920, data-usage

I've recently bought a Nokia Lumia 920 and although my plan at Vodafone NL is pretty large I would like to monitor my data usage.

However I can't seem to find any app that does this.

There is a little scraper app called 'Belstatus Vodafone NL' but that doesn't work for my plan unfortunately.

I looked around on stackexchange and only found this question [Any solution for 3G traffic counting?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/108/any-solution-for-3g-traffic-counting) which does not give me an answer and given the date is probably for WP7 anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the GDR2 update Data Sense should be available on most phones like it was on WP7 as a separate app: counting data from the phones perspective. This can be different from asking the actual network provider for the remaining data in your account (which Data Sense can also do for providers that support it), but it should be able to get you going at least.

(If you have GDR2, GDR3 or later and you still do not see the app, please complain to your provider/carrier, as they have the option to disable this app for their network branded versions of phones. In this case, you just won't be able to find the app anywhere on your phone and there seems to be nothing that you yourself are able to do about this.)

Comment: This is true and I've been happily using this app now since the release of GDR2.

Comment: It should be said this can be removed completely by the operator. For example, my AT&T Lumia 1020 on GDR3 does not have Data Sense at all, not even the phone-side counting, while my unbranded Lumia 920 does have the phone-side counting without the carrier support.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't help you (yet), but Microsoft has an application called [Data Sense](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/start/use-data-sense-to-track-data-usage). Data Sense can monitor and limit your data usage. Unfortunately for some strange reason it is only currently available on Verizon Wireless.

Comment: Any idea of MS is planning to release it for all WP8 phones? Or is it going to be a Verizon exclusive?

Comment: I assume it will be coming to other carriers at some stage.They introduced it as a WP8 feature and the official page says "Data Sense is not currently available for all mobile operators."

Comment: @RoyT. From what I've seen online, it's not really a Microsoft issue - it's a carriers issue. AT&T said in January that it is "exploring" the option.